# .NET authentication - what is difference between SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut() and WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut()

Tags: asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, adfs, adfs2.0

I am new to .NET SSO (Single Sign On and Out) and STS.  For my ASP.NET MVC 5 and C# application, to implement Single Sign Out method, which of the 2 following methods I should use?

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
```

or

```
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Both are needed.

Refer: [Configuring an ASP.NET site to use WS-Federation](http://chris.59north.com/post/2014/08/18/Configuring-an-ASPNET-site-to-use-WS-Federation.aspx).

"The FAM is responsible for looking at the incoming requests and outgoing responses to figure out if the the incoming request is a federation token that needs to be handled, or if the outgoing response is a 401 that needs to be turned into a redirect to the STS.

Once a token has been received and parsed, the FAM uses the SAM to issue a cookie that contains the user identification. This token is then used by the SAM on subsequent requests to authenticate the user."